# How to change drive label using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to mount a couple of network drives and then rename them. However my Powershell script is failing after the first drive renames fine. For the second one I get an error:

```
Exception calling "Put" with "0" argument(s): ""
At C:\Users\ben\Documents\mapdrives.ps1:12 char:11
+ $disk.Put <<<< ()
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

My script looks like this:

```
cls
$Username = ""
$Password = ""
$net = New-Object -com WScript.Network; 

$Drive = "M:"
$UNC = "\\server01\bin$"
$net.mapnetworkdrive($Drive, $Unc, $false, $Username, $Password)
$disk = Get-WmiObject "Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DeviceID='M:'"
if (-not $disk) { return }
$disk.VolumeName = "server1_bin"
$disk.Put()

$Drive = "N:"
$UNC = "\\server01\data$"
$net.mapnetworkdrive($Drive, $Unc, $false, $Username, $Password)
$disk = Get-WmiObject "Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DeviceID='N:'"
if (-not $disk) { return }
$disk.VolumeName = "server1_data"
$disk.Put()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try Like this using comobject for label a drive:

```
$a = New-Object -ComObject shell.application

$a.NameSpace( "M:\" ).self.name = "server1_bin"
```

in any case you need run the console as a user with  administrative rigth

Comment: Interesting. Good example of falling back to the wide array of technologies that PowerShell glues together, when PowerShell itself doesn't have an obvious way to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0):

I have written powershell script

```
function ChangeDriveLabel([string]$driveletter,[string]$newlabel )
{    
    $disk = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = '$driveletter'"

    Set-WmiInstance -input $disk -Arguments @{ Label=$newlabel}

}

ChangeDriveLabel -driveletter 'e:' -newlabel 'DBLOG'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also just run this at the prompt

label c: OS 
to change the drive label to "OS"

label d: Data
to change the drive label to "Data"

To confirm then run diskpart to activate disk partition and then the command list volume at the diskpart prompt to show volumes and their names